# bluemix xpages nosql multiple data sources

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud

I am testen the xpages runtime in BlueMix.
Binding a single xpages nosql service to a Run time is easy.
Now I want on 1 xpage combine data from 2 different nsf files.
is this possible?

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 2):

Found it.
instead of using bluemixContext.getDataService().findDatabaseName() that takes the first data source you can use
bluemixContext.getDataServiceByName(").findDatabaseName()